# how to remove bottom space between bottom of the screen and bottom bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

[image]How to remove white space between bottom bar and bottom of the screen. I also try apply padding or margin in bottom container but its not working . please help me how to resolve this problem .
hey help me  i am afraid about this error . it takes my most of the time but i cant solve it. please help me.

Its my code

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:grk_001/Provider/products.dart';

class ProductDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routename = 'ProductDetails';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final devicesize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final Productid = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;
    final loadedproduct = Provider.of<Products>(
      context,
    ).findByid(Productid);

    return SafeArea(
      maintainBottomViewPadding: true,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(loadedproduct.title == null ? '' : loadedproduct.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 300,
                      child: Image.network(
                        loadedproduct.imageUrl,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '₹${loadedproduct.price}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      loadedproduct.description,
                      softWrap: true,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: FlatButton.icon(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                color: Colors.pink,
                              ),
                              label: Text(
                                'Quantity',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
                              )),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: FlatButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                              color: Colors.pink,
                            ),
                            label: Text(
                              'Color',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 5,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('BUY NOW'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.favorite,
                            size: 37.0,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.shopping_cart,
                            size: 37.0,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Share the code .

Comment: Looks like an outer widget (a parent of the container you posted) has some padding/margin at the bottom.

Comment: If a parent widget padding / margin isn't the issue then wrap your scaffold in a SafeArea and set bottom to true.

Comment: its not working

Comment: Can you share the code with parent widgets?

Comment: of course check it my code , I updated

Comment: Try my answer. It would work for you!

Comment: you are right but my flat button still same but don't worry I use container in place of flat button . thankyou so much your answere is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, found your problem. 
The problem is with your 'BUY NOW' button! It occupies extra height so that it will visible to be high up from the bottom. 
Since your icon's size is 37, a height greater than 37 would be preferred.
Set it for both parent `Container` and Button's `Container`.

 Also, make a note of `crossAxisAlignment` of the `Row`.
Do something like this to your 'BUY NOW' button,

```
    Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 40.0,
            color: Colors.green, 
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40.0,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text('BUY NOW'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        size: 37.0,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.shopping_cart,
                        size: 37.0,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

Hope this solves your issue.